# Absolute Hodge cycles over $\mathbf{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, motives, hodge-theory

In the 1986 notes by Milne "Hodge cycles on abelian varieties", Deligne defines the notion of absolute Hodge cycles.

For a smooth projective variety defined over $k\subset\mathbf{C}$ non algebraically closed, an absolute Hodge cycle is an absolute Hodge cycle on $X_{\overline{k}}$ whose étale component is fixed by the Galois action.

Is it true that for $ k = \mathbf{Q}$, every Hodge cycle is an absolute Hodge cycle? This should be vacuously true, but I don't see it.

Comment: It's not obvious at all. It depends on your definition of absolute Hodge classes. According to Deligne's definition, not only the de Rham component is Hodge under pullback along any field automorphism of $\mathbf{C}$, but also each étale component is Galois invariant and lies in the image of $H^{2*}(X_{\mathbf{C}},\mathbf{Q}(*))$ under Artin's comparison map. Over $\mathbf{Q}$, every Hodge cycle trivially satisfies stability of its dR component under pullback along field automorphisms of $\mathbf{C}$ (it's absolute in the sense of Charles). The étale condition is unclear.

Comment: Over $\mathbf{Q}$, all Hodge cycles are absolute in the sense of Charles. However, the absolute Hodge cycles in the sense of Charles contain the absolute Hodge cycles in the sense of Deligne, and it is an open question whether the containment is an equality.

Comment: I may have been responsible for creating this confusion, in an earlier comment to another question. Anyway I agree, depending on the definition, it's certainly not obvious.